# Como validar campos numéricos no javascript?

Tags: javascript

Preciso monta um código em HTML x Javascript,  com dois campos para digitação de valores numéricos e um botão de
calcular. Ao pressionar o botão calcular, a aplicação deverá emitir na tela o resultado da soma dos dois valores digitados. não estou conseguindo fazer a validação no javascript.

Comment: Se possível clique em [edit] e poste seu código.

Comment: Provavelmente o que tu queres não é validação e sim converter os valores para *int* ou *float*.

Comment: e como faço isso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por padrão, todos os valores dos inputs vêm em como `string`, veja:

```js
document.getElementById('check').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var field = document.getElementById('input');
  
  // Mostra o valor e em seguida o tipo:
  alert(field.value);
  alert(typeof field.value);
});
```

```html
<input id="input" type="number" value="44" />
<button id="check">Clique</button>
```

Desse modo, precisamos transformar o valor do campo em um número.

```
var numberInString = '20';
var number = Number(numberInString);

console.log(typeof number); // number
```

Assim, creio que o que o senhor precisa seja:

```js
document.getElementById('calc-sum').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var num1 = document.getElementById('num-1');
  var num2 = document.getElementById('num-2');
  
  // Transformar os valores em números:
  num1 = Number(num1.value);
  num2 = Number(num2.value);
  
  // Calcular a soma:
  var sum = num1 + num2;
  
  // Mostrar a soma:
  document.getElementById('sum').innerText = 'A soma é: ' + sum;
});
```

```html
<label>Valor 01: </label>
<input id="num-1" type="number" />
<br>
<label>Valor 01: </label>
<input id="num-2" type="number" />
<br><br>
<input type="button" id="calc-sum" value="Calcular soma">
<br><br>
<div id="sum"></div>
```

Nota:

Para converter as `string`s para números, usei o construtor `Number()`.
Mas também poderia-se ter usado os métodos `parseInt()` ou `parseFloat()`.

Comment: valeu mesmo conseguir

Comment: nulo + nulo não é zero

Answer (score 1):

Partindo do principio que o resultado da soma de `(vazio + vazio)` ou `(nulo + nulo)` ou `( e + e )` ou `( espaços + espaços )` não é zero, temos

```js
    function validarNum() {
        var x, texto;

        // Obtem os valores dos campos de entrada com id = "numero"
        x = document.getElementById("numero1").value;
        y = document.getElementById("numero2").value;
        
        z = (parseFloat(x)+parseFloat(y));

        if (isNaN(z)) {
            texto = "Sr. Burro, preencha os campos corretamente";
        } else {
            texto = (parseFloat(x)+parseFloat(y));
        }
        console.log(texto);
    }
```

```html
    <input id="numero1">
    
    <input id="numero2">

    <button type="button" onclick="validarNum()">Somar</button>
```

Comment: Gostei do `Sr. Burro` :D

Comment: Removi aquela resposta lá dos bodes. Achei que não valia a pena porque o problema deve ser essencialmente no PHP: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/291375/8063

Answer (score 0):

Como dito na resposta do [@Luiz Felipe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/291339/8063), é preciso converter o valor dos campos para tipo numérico. No caso aqui usei `parseFloat()`.

Além disso, você pode usar um [avaliador de curto-circuito](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalia%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_curto-circuito) para converter algum o campo que foi deixado vazio em `0`, para evitar o **NaN**.

**Exemplo:**

```js
function calcular(){
   var val1 = parseFloat(document.body.querySelector("#valor1").value) || 0;
   var val2 = parseFloat(document.body.querySelector("#valor2").value) || 0;
                                                                       // ↑
       // caso o campo esteja vazio ou não seja um número, o valor assume 0
   console.log(val1+val2);
}
```

```html
Insira os dois valores (deixe um em branco para testar a soma):
<br>
<input id="valor1">
<input id="valor2">
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button>
```

Comment: muito obrigado.

Comment: muito bom!sou nova nesse mundo de programação rsrs

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo É só para evitar o NaN.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Concordo contigo. Mas como coloquei na resposta, é apenas para converter o nulo em zero, foi só uma sugestão.