# Página multilinguagem sem formatação

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, ajax

Tenho um site multilinguagem utilizando *Ajax*, mas quando coloco para trocar o idioma, a página não sobrepõe formatada.

**www.csvet.com.br**

Ao clicar na bandeira dos EUA no *header* o erro aparece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**O problema é tão somente de CSS.**

> O efeito cascata

Que estilo terá preferência quando um estilo é definido mais de uma vez para o mesmo elemento HTML? Qual das definições o navegador irá aplicar?

> O efeito cascata determina a prioridade para aplicação da regra de estilo ao elemento conforme descrito a seguir e na ordem decrescente de prioridade:

1. folha de estilo do usuário (prioridade mais elevada)
2. folha de estilo do desenvolvedor

   2.1 - dentro de uma tag HTML (definidos através do atributo style nos elementos);

   2.2 - folha de estilo interna (definida na seção HEAD da própria página);

   2.3 - folha de estilo externa (importado ou linkado);

   2.4 - folha de estilo do navegador

**No seu caso ocorre de haver 3 tags body ao longo do código fonte:**

- linha 52 - `<body class="has-side-panel side-panel-right fullwidth-page">`
- Linha 488 - `<body id="cke_pastebin" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; width: 1px; height: 180px; overflow: hidden; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; left: -1000px;">`
- Linha 522 - `<body id="cke_pastebin" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; width: 1px; height: 180px; overflow: hidden; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; left: -1000px;">`

**Que corresponde a situação 2.1 (dentro de uma tag HTML -> tag `body`)**

> Um documento HTML pode definir ou utilizar mais do que uma folha de estilos.
>
> Quando isto ocorre o navegador combina as definições para aplicar ao documento.

Nota-se que no body da linha 52 foi aplicada uma classe

`has-side-panel side-panel-right fullwidth-page`

e nos bodys das linhas 488 e 522 um estilo inline, que por sinal são exatamente identicos,

```
style="position: absolute; top: 10px; width: 1px; height: 180px; overflow: hidden; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; left: -1000px;
```

**O navegador vai combinar e o resultado será**

```
<body class="has-side-panel side-panel-right fullwidth-page" id="cke_pastebin" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; width: 1px; height: 180px; overflow: hidden; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; left: -1000px;">
```

### Finalizando:

Se algum elemento for atingido por duas regras e tiverem a mesma força, a que for declarada por último é a que valerá:

A declaração **left: -1000px**, é a que valerá caso tenha sido declarada também anteriormente `e move o conteúdo 1000 pixels à esquerda da janela visível do navegador`.

Retirando essa declaração sua pagina ficará assim: [**veja no navegador**](http://kithomepage.com/sos/tresbodys-sem-left.htm)

**Como se percebe, ainda com problemas.**

A declaração `overflow: hidden;` esconde o scroll horizontal e vertical.

Retirando essa declaração sua pagina ficará assim: [**veja no navegador**](http://kithomepage.com/sos/tresbodys-sem-left-sem-overflow-hidden.htm)

**Como se percebe, ainda com problemas.**

Retirando o estilo in-line das tags body das linhas 488 e 522  sua pagina ficará assim: [**veja no navegador**](http://kithomepage.com/sos/tresbodys-sem-estilo-inline-nas-bodys.htm)

### Conclusão:

Não há motivo para incluir várias tags body em uma página, utilize apenas uma na linha 53

```
<body class="has-side-panel side-panel-right fullwidth-page" id="cke_pastebin">
```

e seja feliz [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] [**veja no navegador**](http://kithomepage.com/sos/csvet..htm)

<sub>algumas imagens não aparecem no exemplo devido a estarem com url relativos dentro de uma folha de estilos</sub>

Comment: @dvd, explicando do `Caleinicio` até o `Calefin` hahaha. Professor Pasquale explicando tudo nos mínimos detalhes  Tu que é bom em resumir em uma linha, pergunto, como ficaria essa resposta usando operador ternário? :D

Comment: $site = $idioma == 1 ? "pt" : "en";

Comment: @dvd,  `$correto = $tresBodys == 3 ? $tresBodys = 1: "$tresBodys";`