# como fazer a div que esta com width auto não pegar 100% da div pai

Tags: css

estou fazendo um mini chat, estou tendo problema quando a estilização das conversas dos usuários, meu objetivo é fazer com que a `div` que irá mostrar as conversas não fique maior que o seu conteúdo, ou seja se o usuário só digitou uma palavra, ela fica do tamanho dessa palavra, estou tendo problema quanto a isso, tenho a `div` pai que se chama `box_mensagem` e dentro dessa `div` tenho as `li` que vão segurar as conversas dos usuários, e dentro dessas `li` tenho a `div box_msg` que pega `100%` da `div` que é a `box_mensagem`e dentro dessa `box_msg` enfim tenho a `div` que segura toda a minha conversa é a div `segura_msg` por padrão ela tem um `float: left;` e para identificar quando é eu que mando a mensagem adicionei a classe `eu` com um `float: right;`, e essa `div` tem um `width: 400px;` que limita o tamando dela, e dentro dela tenho a div que mostra a foto e a mensagem do usuário com o `width: auto;`, só que estou com problemas quanto a isso, a minha mensagem era para ficar na direita, e a foto fora dessa `div` com `width: auto;` porém quando eu do uma margin negativa na foto, ela acaba sumindo da `div`, oque estou fazendo de errado ?
http://prntscr.com/j5dvm8

```
<style type="text/css">
.align_left {
    float: left;
}
.box_mensagem {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.box_mensagem::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
}
.box_mensagem ul li .box_msg {
    margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
    width: 570px;   
    height: 120px;
    background-color: purple;
}
.box_mensagem ul li:last-child .box_msg {
    margin: 0;
}
#chat #left #mensagem .box_mensagem ul li .box_msg .segura_msg {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
}
.box_mensagem ul li .box_msg .eu,
.box_mensagem ul li .box_msg .segura_msg .m_msg {
    float: right;
}
.box_mensagem ul li .box_msg .segura_msg .mostra_msg {
    float:  left;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.box_mensagem ul li .box_msg .segura_msg img {
    float: left;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
}
</style>

<div class="box_mensagem align_left">
                <ul>
                    <li><div class="box_msg">
                        <div class="segura_msg">
                            <div class="mostra_msg">
                                <img src="fotos/1.jpg" border="0">
                                aqui vem a primeira conversa do chat
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div></li>
                    <li><div class="box_msg">
                        <div class="segura_msg eu">
                            <div class="mostra_msg m_msg">
                                <img src="fotos/2.jpg" border="0">
                                aqui vem o usuário 02 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: O seu CSS só tem `id`s `#` mas o HTML mostrado não tem 1 elemento com uma dessas `id`s.

Comment: o css esta mostrando toda a minha estrutura, vou editar a pergunta

Comment: agora melhorou, mas não consegui entender oq vc quer fazer...

Comment: por exemplo, a pessoa que está conversando comigo digita por exemplo, "tudo bem?", a div que mostra a foto e a mensagem que ela escreveu só pega o tamanho da mensagem, e a foto ganhar uma margin negativa, pra fica fora dessa div, e quando eu respondo a mesma coisa, só que a minha div tem que ter um `float: right` entendeu ? a `div m_msg` quer dizer minha mensagem, eu dei um `float: right` nela só que não pegou

Comment: parecido com isso amigo, http://prntscr.com/j5ea89

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugiro que altere alguns códigos do CSS, como por exemplo, criar uma outra classe para mensagens recebidas. As suas mensagens possuem as classes `.eu` e `.m_msg`, logo você pode criar outras duas classes `.ele` e `.e_msg`. Desta forma fica bem mais fácil de estilizar cada coisa de forma independente, como atribuir um `float` diferente, uma margem diferente e posicionar a imagem de cada `div`.

A imagem você pode posicionar de forma absoluta (`position: absolute`) já que a posição dela será sempre a mesma.

Veja como ficaria da forma mencionada:

```css
.align_left {
    float: left;
}
.box_mensagem {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.box_mensagem::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
}
.box_mensagem ul li .box_msg {
    margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
    width: 570px;   
    height: 120px;
    background-color: purple;
}
.box_mensagem ul li:last-child .box_msg {
    margin: 0;
}
.box_mensagem ul li .box_msg .segura_msg {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
}

.box_mensagem ul li .box_msg .eu
{
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}

.mostra_msg {
    float:  left;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: relative;
}

.mostra_msg img {
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

div.m_msg{
    margin-right: 55px;
    float: right;
}

div.e_msg{
    margin-left: 55px;
}

.eu .mostra_msg img{
   right: -55px;
}

.ele .mostra_msg img{
   left: -55px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box_mensagem align_left">
    <ul>
        <li><div class="box_msg">
            <div class="segura_msg ele">
                <div class="mostra_msg e_msg">
                    <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" border="0">
                    aqui vem a primeira conversa do chat aqui vem a primeira conversa do chat aqui vem a primeira conversa do chat aqui vem a primeira conversa do chat
                </div>
            </div>
        </div></li>
        <li><div class="box_msg">
            <div class="segura_msg eu">
                <div class="mostra_msg m_msg">
                    <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" border="0">
                    aqui vem a primeira conversa do chat aqui vem a primeira conversa
                </div>
            </div>
        </div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Coloquei uma resposta lá, veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/291375/p%C3%A1gina-multilinguagem-sem-formata%C3%A7%C3%A3o/291420#291420